# MySql: does it have namespace-like SCHEMA?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have to move a database from sql server to mySql, and our current db uses schemas as namespace.

So all of the FOO tables can be reference like FOO.TableFoo1, FOO.TAbleFoo2, FOO.TableF003, etc.

Can we do this with MySql? Will it work.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Yes in mysql you can have many schema, select the schema you want to use with the `USE` command or the mysql_select_db() API. You can also do cross-schema queries, as in

```
SELECT * FROM `FOO`.`TABLEFOO1`, `BAR`.`TABLEBAR1` WHERE ...
```

You create and delete schema using `CREATE DATABASE FOO` and `DROP DATABASE BAR`.

Comment: I think the MySQL term for those is simply "Database": http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/use.html

Comment: Thanks! Got mixed up with the vocabulary :)

Answer (score 4):

That is wrong Joachim. A database is not a schema. Try buying hosting where you only get 20 databases but you need 33. With a schema you can use only one database and have many tables with the same name but different schema.

Comment: I think the better place for that would have been as a commend below his on the other answer.

Comment: I think just to clarify: In MySQL (Which is what this question is tagged), A schema is synonymous with database, ALTHOUGH, in other sql servers they do have 2 distinct different meanings.